# Update PDF annotation / textbox content c#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I have a PDF which I have added a text box to and set the value to "XXXX".

Using Pdfsharp I have created function which finds that text box and updates the content to "MMMM"

```
    PdfDocument doc = PdfReader.Open(@"C:\Form.pdf"); 
    
    PdfPage page = doc.Pages[0]; 
    var anno = page.Annotations[0]; 
    page.Annotations.Remove(page.Annotations[0]); 
    
    var newAnno = (PdfAnnotation)anno.Clone(); 
    
    newAnno.Contents = "MMMMM"; 
    
    // Add the annotation to the page 
    page.Annotations.Add(newAnno); 
    
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance); 
    
    doc.Save(@"C:\Form-2.pdf");
```

However when I open Form-2.pdf I still see "XXXX". When I click on it, it immediately changes to "MMMM". Is there anyway to force update the annotation without clicking?